# jade each get error passing object from the controller

Tags: node.js, pug

Why with this code

controller.js

```
'use strict';
var assetmanager = require('assetmanager');
var assets ={1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'};
exports.render = function(config) {
     //var assets = require(config.sroot+'/config/assets.json');
   /* assetmanager.init({
        js: assets.js,
        css: assets.css,
        debug: (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),
        webroot: config.proot+'/public'
    });*/
    console.log(assets);
    return function(req, res) {
        res.render('layouts/default', {'appTitle':'ilwebdifabio','assets':assets});
    }
};
```

layout.jade

```
each val,index in assets
            link(rel='stylesheet', href=val)
        script.
            var nB = nB || {};
            nB.user = !{JSON.stringify(assets)};
```

I get **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

in the nB.user  there is the object so I don't know which way to turn :(

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you don't have a blank line at the end of your Jade template.  Add a blank line after

```
nB.user = !{JSON.stringify(assets)};
```